# Calculate state transition matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix, control-theory

Is there a direct way to calculate state transition matrix(i.e. e^(A*t), where A is a matrix)? 
I planned to calculate it in this way:

[image: x(t) is the e^(A*t) and x(0)=1]

but failed:

[image: failed when calculate inverse laplace tansform]

And if I directly calculate A*t first and then use `expm()`, it still cannot work since there should be no variable in `expm()`.

I hope I illustrate my problem clearly :)

EDIT: Here is the code I think should be useful to solve my problem:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import quad


Ts=0.02
s=sympy.symbols('s')
t=sympy.symbols('t')
T0=np.matrix([[1,0,0],
              [0,1,0],
              [0,-1,1]])
M0=np.matrix([[1.735,0.15851,0.042262],
              [0.123728,0.07019322,0.02070838],
              [0.042262,0.0243628,0.014375212]])
F0=np.matrix([[-22.915,0,0],
              [0,-0.00969,0.00264],
              [0,0.00264,-0.00264]])
N0=np.matrix([[0,0,0],
              [0,1.553398,0],
              [0,0,0.4141676]])
G0=np.matrix([[11.887],[0],[0]])
Ky=np.matrix([1.0121,4.5728,6.3652,0.9117,1.5246,0.9989])
A21=T0*(M0.I)*N0*(T0.I)
A22=T0*(M0.I)*F0*(T0.I)
Z=np.zeros((3,3))
Y=(np.matrix([0,0,0])).T
by1=np.row_stack((Z,A21))
by2=np.row_stack((np.identity(3),A22))
A=np.column_stack((by1,by2))
G=scipy.linalg.expm(A*Ts)


B2=T0*(M0.I)*G0
B=np.row_stack((Y,B2))
S1=sympy.Matrix((s*np.identity(6))-A)
S2=S1.inv()
S=S2
for (i,j), orinm in scipy.ndenumerate(S2):
    S[i,j]=sympy.inverse_laplace_transform(orinm, s, t)

#integral
H=np.zeros(S2.shape, dtype=float)
for (i,j),func_sympy in scipy.ndenumerate(S2):
    func = sympy.lambdify( (t),func_sympy, 'math')
    H[i,j] = quad(func, 0, 0.02)[0]
print(H)
```

Comment: Looks like a lot of matrix inversion.  Are those matrices guaranteed to be invertible?  (positve definite, or some such?)

Comment: I think yes.Those matrices are guaranteed to be invertible, since it actually is an example from book and someone made it using MATLAB. I have supplemented the code and you may have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly calculate the matrix exponential using `scipy`.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import expm

A = np.random.random((10, 10))
exp_A = expm(A)
```

The documentation for this is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.expm.html) It uses the Pade approximation.

Here is an example using the 2x2 identity matrix.

```
>>> expm(np.eye(2))
array([[2.71828183, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 2.71828183]])
```

If you need the matrix exponential of a symbolic matrix (as per your comment) then you can do this with Sympy:

```
t = sympy.symbols('t')
A = sympy.Matrix([[t, 0], [0, t]])
>>> sympy.exp(A)
Matrix([
[expt(t), 0],
[0,  exp(t)]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the issue is the matrix A of expm(A) cannot include symbols/variables(e.g. A=matrix([[t,3],[t,t**2]])). TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational. Is there a way to calculate this kind of matrix exponential?

Comment: @YuTsing I've added a Sympy example to the answer which I think is what you are after.

Comment: This is quite useful! However, I got a new problem with it and maybe you can help me to solve it: Exponentiation is implemented only for matrices for which the Jordan normal form can be computed.